# How to Balance?

Tags: lateral-thinking, weighing

You are given a scale which has 4kg and 2kg stones on the left side and an 8kg stone on the right side of the scale. You have an additional 1kg. How will you balance the scale?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is one way to do it

> Remove all of the weights (leaving zero on each side of the scale)

Comment: You put a noodle on it.